# Deploy Blazor Wasm with Docker from Visual Studio

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I want to deploy my Blazor Webassambly App to a Docker Container to run it on my synology NAS.

So my problem is now, that since I want to run my Webassembly App in my VisualStudio IDE with Docker, I have an error "The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in ..."

Has anyone an idea what i could do do solve this error?

Here is the full console output:

```
    docker exec -i -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT="55427" -w "C:\app" d274a895523ac47657707b86a7df5ea304df8bfe68330a64b00d9cc357ed1546 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --additionalProbingPath c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages2 --additionalProbingPath c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages  "C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.dll"
Cannot use file stream for [C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.deps.json]: No such file or directory
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
docker exec -i -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT="55427" -w "C:\app" d274a895523ac47657707b86a7df5ea304df8bfe68330a64b00d9cc357ed1546 "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --additionalProbingPath c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages2 --additionalProbingPath c:\\.nuget\\fallbackpackages  "C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.dll"
Cannot use file stream for [C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.deps.json]: No such file or directory
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\app\bin\Debug\net5.0\Jordan_Webapp_Client.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
```

And here is my Docker File:

````
#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Jordan_Webapp_Client/Jordan_Webapp_Client.csproj", "Jordan_Webapp_Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Jordan_Webapp_Client/Jordan_Webapp_Client.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Jordan_Webapp_Client"
RUN dotnet build "Jordan_Webapp_Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Jordan_Webapp_Client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Jordan_Webapp_Client.dll"] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a private nuget feed, try changing the "RUN dotnet restore..." command.

Example:

```
RUN dotnet restore -s "https://your-nuget-feed.example.com/nuget" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"  "Jordan_Webapp_Client/Jordan_Webapp_Client.csproj"
```